# Frame and Image in specific aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, frame, core-image

I created empty gray UIImage, using below code

```
let size = CGSize(width: 212, height: 332)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
UIColor.gray.setFill()
UIRectFill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
let backgroundImage2: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

It shows output as 
[image]

Now I need to put UIImage on specific area in this UIImage. as shown in below Image. Say top, left, right should be 30 pixels, and bottom more than that, say 200 pixels. maintaining inner image aspect ratio.

[image]

Comment: You can draw image using drawInRect method and added as per provided rect . That what you need ?

Comment: @MikeAlter I did that but issue is to maintain aspect ratio while doing Draw(in: rect: )

Comment: Even if you make small demo at your end, you will be facing same aspect ratio issue @MikeAlter

Comment: why you don't use two image views or one gray background view and image view in the foreground

Comment: as I need to send editted image to server, merged one, containing text, background, foreground , all in one image @SaeedRahmatolahi

Answer (score 0):

Use two image views (either `UIImageView` or `GLKView`), making the "image" a subview of the "gray background" view. After positioning the "image" correctly, merge the two images into one.

Here's an extension to `UIView` that I use:

```
extension UIView {
    public func createImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height), true, 1)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```